# Set the width of the select box in Drupal form

Tags: forms, 6

Currently I have a select box in a form as follows :

```
$form['fieldset']['event_trigger'] = array('#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('E-mail event trigger'),
    //'#default_value' => $edit['mail'],
    '#size' =>20
    //'#options' => select_eventtrigger_dropdown(),
    '#description' => t('A valid e-mail address. All e-mails from the system will be sent to this address. The e-mail address is not made public and will only be used if you wish to receive a new password or wish to receive certain news or notifications by e-mail.'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );
```

But here `#size` attribute is not fitting my requirement. It should have been the width of the select box.  How can I achieve this or is there any workaround?

Comment: use `css` by the ID or any other selector that is related to this select box

Answer (score 1):

The size attribute you are trying to set there is related to how many items are shown at one time. So in those terms the height would increase and it would show a scrolling list of items to choose from if you added size to the select box. See [Form API Docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/6#size) for more information.

You need to target the select box with CSS to change the width (most themes/browsers set the width of a select box to `width: auto;` so it would be as long as the longest item to be selected).

So for instance if you want to set all of your `select` elements to take up the entire width of their containing divs you would set:

```
select {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Or if you want to target all select elements with a class of `.form-select` you could use:

```
select.form-select {
  width: 50em;
}
```

You can use id's also like `select#id-of-element` but using a class is the more generally accepted best practice for styling (not just in Drupal but general FED practices also).

Answer (score 1):

In the Drupal 8 forms api, any form element attributes not directly supported by the API get stuffed into the '#attributes' FormElement property. This property supports the entire HTML spec for form element tag html attributes, as far as I know. It's the catch-all for anything the Drupal development folks don't feel the need to directly define and model.

```
$form['fieldset']['event_trigger'] = array('#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('E-mail event trigger'),
    '#size' =>20
    '#description' => t('A valid e-mail address. All e-mails from the system will be sent to this address. The e-mail address is not made public and will only be used if you wish to receive a new password or wish to receive certain news or notifications by e-mail.'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#attributes' => [
      'style' => 'width: 50em;'
    ],
  );
```

**or (usually preferred)**

```
$form['fieldset']['event_trigger'] = array('#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('E-mail event trigger'),
    '#size' =>20
    '#description' => t('A valid e-mail address. All e-mails from the system will be sent to this address. The e-mail address is not made public and will only be used if you wish to receive a new password or wish to receive certain news or notifications by e-mail.'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#attributes' => [
      'class' => 'select-css'
    ],
  );
```

coupled with a stylesheet:

```
.select-css {
  width: 50em;
}
```